# Ionic android build stucked at Starting a Gradle Daemon

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build

I have a project that is running on Ionic. I've worked on it for one month without any problems. Now after some delay i returned back to the project. When i try to build project on iOS, everything is OK. When i'm trying to build project on Android, i'm stucked on building. Command that i'm running is

**ionic cordova emulate android -lc**

Build is stucked on command

**cordova build android**

When i try to run this command in terminal, i have this forever loop :

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/jakub.bajzath/Library/Android/sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jakub.bajzath/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 80 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 81 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 82 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> IDLE
```

What i tried?

- Delete gradle from system
- Install gradle by homebrew
- Update ionic, cordova etc.
- Change variable org.gradle.daemon
- Update propect.properties with variables
- Restart computer
- Stopped all running daemons
- Open in Android Studio (same, stucked on Gradle sync)
- Checked internet connection (everything is OK, proxy turned off - even for ESET Security)

I'm done here with this issue, i'm not able to run project on android device (emulator or real device). I tried to Google, tried to search here, no success. Can you please help me? Any ideas?

UPDATE : ionic info output

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.1.0 (/Users/jakub.bajzath/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.2, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.9.0) : 0.6.0
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0)  : 0.2.9

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/jakub.bajzath/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.4
   ios-sim           : 8.0.2
   NodeJS            : v12.10.0 (/Users/jakub.bajzath/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.13.7
   OS                : macOS Catalina
   Xcode             : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

Comment: Run command: `ionic info` and add output to your Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like antivirus program was the problem. Even when i had everything turned off in ESET (Firewall, proxy, web services etc.), Gradle was stucked. When i completely uninstalled ESET on my Mac, Gradle and build process started to work. So my answer is uninstall antivirus program.